# Thinktecture IdentityServer 3 - ASP.NET Identity sample not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, thinktecture-ident-server

I'm running the IdentityServer AspNetIdentity sample from https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/AspNetIdentity. By itself, with the database in app.config set to (LocalDb), it works.

I've also done File/New Project on an MVC 5 + Web API 2 project. I've created a SQL database in Azure SQL, pointed the new project to that database, and created a new user in there, which means that ASP.NET Identity has run the database creation scripts, and I have the usual tables in there.

So, separately, they're fine.

I then went into the AspNetIdentity sample, and pointed it at the newly-created SQL database that was just populated. When I run the sample... it blows up. Specifically, in AspNetIdentityUserService.cs, on line 188, where it calls into UserManager.

```
    protected async virtual Task<TUser> FindUserAsync(string username)
    {
        return await userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
    }
```

Exception:

```
SelfHost.vshost.exe Error: 0 : [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Configuration.Hosting.ErrorPageFilterAttribute]: 8/20/2015 7:26:40 PM +00:00 -- Exception accessing: /core/login
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'FirstName'. Invalid column name 'LastName'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c__DisplayClass16.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__17(Task`1 result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.<ExecuteStoreCommandsAsync>d__c.MoveNext()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.<ExecuteStoreCommandsAsync>d__c.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
etc.
```

Am I misunderstanding something? Shouldn't the AspNetIdentity plugin be able to pull from a normally-formatted ASP.NET Identity database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sample is using an extended version of the base ASP.NET Identity `IdentityUser`. See the [`User` entity](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/AspNetIdentity/WebHost/AspId/SimpleEntities.cs#L27).

This has the added properties of `FirstName` and `LastName`, which according to your exception, your database does not have.

Comment: Scott - Thanks for the answer and for your blog posts, like https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Identity-Server-3-using-ASPNET-Identity. Very helpful, indeed.

Comment: No worries, glad it helped!